# React component always gives last given props value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Child Component

```
export class MultiSelectDrawer extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    window.onpopstate = ()=>{
      console.log(this.props.id);
    }
  }
  render() {
    const {input, id, label, showActionDrawer, toggleActionDrawer, items, closeActionDrawer} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
MultiSelectDrawer.contextTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default MultiSelectDrawer;
```

Parent component

```
<td style={Object.assign({},styles.filters, styles.leftAlign)}>
     <Field id="stateSearchFilter" name="stateSearchFilter" component={MultiSelectDrawer} label={this.context.t("State")} items={states} titleField='value' toggleActionDrawer = {toggleActionDrawerState} showActionDrawer = {this.state.showActionDrawerState} closeActionDrawer = {closeActionDrawerStateFilter} filterBar={filterBar}></Field>
</td>
<td style={Object.assign({},styles.filters, styles.leftAlign)}>
     <Field id="prioritySearchFilter" name="prioritySearchFilter" component={MultiSelectDrawer} label={this.context.t("Priority")} items={priorities} titleField='label' toggleActionDrawer = {toggleActionDrawerPriority} showActionDrawer = {this.state.showActionDrawerPriority} closeActionDrawer = {closeActionDrawerPriorityFilter} filterBar={filterBar}></Field>
</td>
```

In the child componentDidMount window.onpopstate log I am expecting to see both the ids printed when browser back button is pressed. But it is only printing the second id which is prioritySearchFilter. I am quite new to React. What is wrong i am doing here?

Comment: Maybe you should store the id in state and update state with `componentWillReceiveProps` when props are changing?

Comment: The props are not changing. I am initialising the  child component with two different sets of properties. When the browser back button is pressed i want see two log with two different id but I see only one. So only one of them are getting called and not the other. I want to know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting your first function.
You are calling:

```
 window.onpopstate = ()=>{
      console.log(this.props.id);
    }

 window.onpopstate = ()=>{
      console.log(this.props.id);
    }
```

twice (in each component instance). So its like when you assign two values to the same variable (here the variable is window.onpopstate). The last assignment overwrites the first.

```
var x = 1;
x = 2 // now x is 2. previous value is overwritten.
```

Or in your case:

```
window.onpopstate = func1;
window.onpopstate = func2;
```

After these two calls `window.onpopstate` now points to `func2`

Comment: Now I got the issue. Although I am calling them from different component. They are the same function.Thanks

Comment: Yes because window is a global variable. Every piece of code sees the same instance of window.